# What's the approach to solving this kind of logic problem?

Tags: algorithm, logic

What would be the approach to a kind of problem that sounds like this:

A says B lies

B says C lies

D says B lies

C says B lies

E says A and D lie

How many lie and how many tell the truth?
I am not looking for the answer to the problem above, but the approach to this kind of problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean the approach to solving this programatically?

Comment: Are you looking for a programming solution or mathematical solution? In later case http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yes the approach to solve this type of problem using a programming language such as C, Java rather than prolog or clips

Comment: @Task: No, it is not suited for cstheory as it is not reasearch level. This is well known enough to be homework, in fact.

Comment: @Aryabhatta, I only though about cstheory as this can be solved by using discrete math/logic theory without programming. The OP has confirmed that he is looking for programming solution. I was not sure, that why I haven't casted any close vote, just commented.

Comment: @task: I am talking about the site cstheory.stackexchange.com. That site is for reasearch level questions only.

Comment: @Aryabhatta, then my mistake. I had a wrong idea about that. I thought that is for theoretical questions, didn't know that is only for research level questions. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Does a liar always lie? Say, A is a liar and A says B is lying. Does that mean B is a truth sayer? Or does it mean B can be either a liar or a truth sayer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A -> !B
B -> !C
D -> !B
C -> !B
E -> !A & !D
```

Reminder:

```
X -> Y  <=>  !X | Y
```

Transform the 5 equations into logical propositions, and you will find answers.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach allow liars to tell the truth? If the only condition was that `X -> Y` and we considered the logical equivalent `!X | Y`, that has a truthy value unless Y==0 and X==1, allowing X and Y to be *simultaneously* liars. But if X==Y==0 and they're liars, then X said Y is a truth-teller, and thus a liar told the truth. Maybe that's what the OP wanted, but other answers seem to assume that liars always lie...

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is on topic with the above comments but liars always lie and those who tell the truth always tell the truth

Comment: @DDD, in which case this answer won't lead to a valid solution.

Comment: In my answer, `A -> !B` means "if A says the truth, B lies".


Now, if "A says B lies" means that "if A says the truth then B lies" AND "if A lies then B says the truth", then you should interpret "A says B lies" as `A -> !B` AND `A <- !B` which is equivalent to `A == !B`.

Comment: I am still not sure about how to interpret the question. Because in one case, the presence of both "B says C lies" and "C says B lies" is a suspect redondancy.

Answer (score 5):

To solve equations of the form

> X<sub>1</sub> = NOT X <sub>3</sub>
>
> X<sub>5</sub> = NOT X <sub>2</sub>
>
> etc

Form a graph with nodes as X<sub>i</sub> and connecting X<sub>i</sub> and X <sub>j</sub> iff the equation X<sub>i</sub> = NOT X <sub>j</sub> appears.

Now try to 2-colour the graph using Breadth First Search.

Comment: I would have thought "A says B and C both lie" is logically equivalent to "A --> !B" and "A --> !C", which is still 2-SAT. Am I missing something?

Comment: @david: I made a mistake: I transformed A implies B to NOT A or NOT B, instead of NOT A or B. Corrected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The comments above are for the previous answer to the previous question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're looking to solve this with a program... it's actually pretty easy to brute force, if you've got a reasonably small input set. For example, in this case you've basically got 5 Boolean variables - whether each person is a truth-teller or not.

Encode the statements as tests, and then run through every possible combination to see which ones are valid.

This is obviously a "dumb" solution and will fail for large input sets, but it's likely to be rather easier to code than a full "reasoning" engine. Often I find that you can get away with doing a lot less work by taking into account what size of problem you're actually going to encounter :)

Comment: Isn't this the famed SAT-problem, though?

Comment: @csl: Not sure what you mean. Reference?

Comment: Boolean satisfiability, which is known to be NP-complete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Comment: @csl: Ah, I thought you were talking about a high school SAT test. Yes, it's Boolean satisfiability. I'm not sure how that affects my answer though... for small inputs you can brute force it. For large inputs you *may* be able to write code to reason about it more efficiently... but in some cases it will simply be "hard".

Comment: @Jon: Heh, well I was just referring to your comment about it being easy to brute force.  For five instances, sure.  Worth mentioning in an answer.

Comment: @csl: Well I did explicitly say "if you've got a reasonably small input set". There will obviously be 2^N possibilities to test for N variables, and then you've got to test each of the conditions for each possibility.

Comment: In its current form, it is only 2-SAT which is still solvable in polynomial time. To become 3-SAT (and hence NP-complete), the problem would need to have statements such as "A says 'B says C lies'".

Comment: @Jon: I don't disagree with what you wrote but I didn't think this was a +5 level answer. That's all!

Comment: @John: I guess everyone votes how they see fit, but I wouldn't downvote an answer unless I considered it "not useful" (or in my case, *actively* unhelpful). Hence the tooltip. Downvotes are best used to indicate that something is *wrong* with an answer (or a question is badly written etc).

Answer (score 0):

Use a logic programming language such as Prolog. They are specifically designed to solve such problems.

Other alternatives include functional-logic languages and model checkers.

Comment: He asked for the _approach_, not a program that executes it for you.

Comment: Yes, but programmers should learn to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Agreed, but then it'd be better to teach about backtracking or Horn logic, for instance.  Or specifically, how to _solve_ this problem.