# Liars and Truthtellers problem

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the approach to solving this kind of logic problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000632/whats-the-approach-to-solving-this-kind-of-logic-problem)

Here is my scenario:
We are given N people who can be liars or truthtellers. A liar always tells lies and a truthteller always tells the truth.
We have a list with their responses. Each of them answers who is a liar. Example :

```
A 1
B
B 1
C
D 1
B
C 1
B
E 2
D
A
```

A says that B is a liar.
B says that C is a liar.
[...]
E says that D and A are liars.

I want to find out the 2 numbers ( the group of liars and the group of truthtellers). For the above the answer is [3,2]. Which is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Homework? Should tag it.

Comment: Need more info. Does truthteller identify _all_ the liars? Does liar lie arbitrary or inverts truth (returns the list of truthtellers)? How can "the group of liars" be a number?

Comment: do we need to connect from the group size to which group it is? it might be impossible. a toy example: 1) two liars (yields no answer) 2) two truthtellers (yields no answer)

Comment: i'm sorry. I meant the number of the people in the 2 groups, in case it's possible to find them(it's not guaranteed). A truthteller doesn't have answers for everybody, nor the liar.

Comment: @Dan Dinu: is it guaranteed it is possible to identify who is a liar and who is a truthteller? should we be able to identify it is not possible?

Comment: @Dan Dinu: Homework I'm guessing? If so, tag it as such.