# Boolean system ( for C++/ C#/java)

Tags: algorithm

How can I programatically resolve this type of system :

```
A = !B
B = !C
D = !B
E = !A
E = !B
```

so I can get by substituting `A = C = D (3)` and `E = B (2)`. I only need the number of the 2 groups. If it's not possible to get 2 groups, I display an error message.

Comment: Related (and I would like to say "duplicate"): [How many lie and how many tell the truth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000632/whats-the-approach-to-solving-this-kind-of-logic-problem)

Comment: i didn't see his edit, but i would much more appreciate an answer to the problem. It hasn't been solved:)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question asks for the basic approach, which is given. This question is more specific, asking for implementation details.

Comment: @IVlad: I still think it is dupe, as the approach of 2-coloring a graph (see my answer there) can also be implemented easily.

Comment: @Dan Dinu, by the way, I think if you do not plan to spend much time on this homework, you can just use Jon Skeet's brute force approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case, this is not closed as a dupe, from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000632/whats-the-approach-to-solving-this-kind-of-logic-problem/6000708#6000708) in your previous question:

To solve equations of the form

> X<sub>1</sub> = NOT X <sub>3</sub>
>
> X<sub>5</sub> = NOT X <sub>2</sub>
>
> etc

Form a graph with nodes as X<sub>i</sub> and connecting X<sub>i</sub> and X <sub>j</sub> iff the equation X<sub>i</sub> = NOT X <sub>j</sub> appears.

Now try to 2-colour the graph using Breadth First Search.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I had the graph idea but i gave up very fast. I still  don't think i get the idea. You're saying to connect nodes Xi and Xj for each equation, but in the end i get a connected graph

Comment: @Dan: Great that you get a connected graph. What is your question?

Comment: i don't understand how can i figure out what the 2 groups are, if the graph is entirely connected. (case there are only 2 groups)

Comment: @Dan: Do you know what a 2-colouring means?

Comment: the graph in my example above is the following : A linked to B; B linked to C; B linked to D, E linked to A and B ; If i undestand what you mean, i have to give the nodes 2 colors so that adiacent nodes won't have the same color. But how can i do this in this example? A is connected to B; B to E and E to A. If A is black then E and B are white, but E and B are adiacent. Am i wrong?

Comment: @DAn: The equations A = !B, E = !A and E = !B are inconsistent and so there is no 2-colouring. In graph theoretic terms, ABE forms an odd cycle. It is well known that a graph is 2-colourable iff it has no odd cycles. If the graph you from has no 2 colouring, then the system of equations is inconsistent.

Comment: thank you i got it. is there a way of checking if the graph is colorable, without actually colour it?

Answer (score -1):

Consider a string of bits `ABCDE`. For each [subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of this string, set all the variables in that subset to `true` and all the variables not in the subset to `false`. See which subset matches your conditions.

You can implement this by counting in binary from `0` to `2^(num variables) - 1`. For each number, its binary representation gives you which variables are `true` and which are `false`. So you just need to get all the bits of a number and do your checks.

Comment: although easy to implement this is a so called *brute force* solution usually frowned upon within the academic community.